# Unsafe characters for programming and MySQL queries/databases

Tags: mysql

Im limiting my clients from entering certain characters.

Right now I allow:

- All the numbers
- All the english letters
- -
- _

I do not allow:

- '
- "
- ;

What other safe characters and/or unsafe characters exist when doing a query via programming using a textbox or such?

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to work with any SQL (MySQL included) is to use parameterized queries.  This will allow your clients to enter any characters they want and prevent any SQL injections.

You didn't mention what language you are working with so here's a .NET example for working with MySQL:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html

Comment: the php options are mysqli or pdo. personal preference is for pdo

Comment: Sadly, I cannot use parameterized queries as the option is not avaliable here. Thats why I wanted to see if there was a MySQL function I could send in the query that the server safely interprets the query.

Comment: Why can't you use parameterized queries?  What's preventing them?

Comment: @BlargleMonster Not supported, sadly.